# Angular subscribe data to show in Form UI

Tags: angular, typescript, object, angular-forms

I try to pass this item details to form. But I don't undefined for this.itemDetails.item1Qty etc. I want to show in Form UI.

```js
this.wareHouseGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: this.formBuilder.control(this.warehouse.id),

  sideId: this.formBuilder.control(this.warehouse.sideId.toString(), [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.min(1)
  ]),
 itemDetail: this.formBuilder.group({
    Item1Qty: this.formBuilder.control(this.itemDetails.item1Qty),
    item2Qty: this.formBuilder.control(this.itemDetails.item2Qty),
    item3Qty: this.formBuilder.control(this.itemDetails.item3Qty)
  })
});
  this.itemService.getItemDetails(this.item.uid).subscribe((result) => {
      this.itemDetails = result != null ? result : null;

      console.log(this.itemDetails);
    });

here is the console log
{"id":117,"TypeId":1,"item1Qty":563,"item2Qty":3.00,"item3Qty":0,"itemType":"Discount"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly assign the `itemDetails` value when initializing/building form as `itemDetails` data only returned during the subscription.

```js
itemDetail: this.formBuilder.group({
    Item1Qty: this.formBuilder.control(this.itemDetails.item1Qty),
    item2Qty: this.formBuilder.control(this.itemDetails.item2Qty),
    item3Qty: this.formBuilder.control(this.itemDetails.item3Qty)
})
```

---

### Solution

Instead, you should do the below steps:

**(1): Remove initialize `itemDetails` when building form**

```js
itemDetail: this.formBuilder.group({
    Item1Qty: this.formBuilder.control(''),
    item2Qty: this.formBuilder.control(''),
    item3Qty: this.formBuilder.control('')
})
```

**(2) In the subscription event, update the form with the value via `patchValue`.**

```js
this.itemService.getItemDetails(this.item.uid).subscribe(result => {
    this.itemDetails = result != null ? result : null;

    if (!result) return;

    this.wareHouseGroup.controls['itemDetail'].patchValue({
      Item1Qty: this.itemDetails.item1Qty,
      item2Qty: this.itemDetails.item2Qty,
      item3Qty: this.itemDetails.item3Qty
    });

    console.log(this.itemDetails);
});
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-28dtly)

---

### References

[Updating parts of the data model](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. @YongShun I did try to do . When I do  console.log(this.itemDetails); I got [object][object].

Comment: Can you create Minimal Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)? Would like to know the `itemDetails` type and also the response result returned by the API.

Comment: This is the response result returned by API{"id":117,"TypeId":1,"item1Qty":563,"item2Qty":3.00,"item3Qty":0,"itemType":"Discount"} . Also if I do window.alert(JSON.stringify(this. itemDetails)), the above JSON string will show.

Comment: itemDetails is the object

Comment: Try to apply `itemDetails` as `any` type or specify its type as class/interface by creating the class/interfcae.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. It is because I didn't match the property name with API endpoints. Thanks for your help @Yong Shun. Saved my day :)